# recommended way to find a word in a comma-separated string?

Tags: java, string

I want to find if a `utility` is in one of the `utilities`.

I have a `JUnit` test as following

```
@Test
public void testUtilityInUtilities() {
    final String utilities = "Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E),San Diego Gas & Electric (SDG&E), Salt River Project (SRP),Southern California Edison (SCE)";
    final String utility = "San Diego Gas & Electric (SDG&E)";
    assertTrue(utilities.contains(utility));
}
```

Is it a good enough test? or shall I do something similar to following?

```
String[] splitString = (utilities.split(","));
for (String string : splitString) {
    if (string.equals(utility)) {return true;}
}
return false;
```

which method is recommended? **split** or **contains** or anything else?

Answer (score 3):

The `contains` way is faster, but it is prone to false positives: it will match a sub-string, say, `"Gas & Electric"`, even though the actual string was `"Pacific Gas & Electric (PG&E)"`. You can guard against this by requiring that the points around the match be at an end of the string or at a comma. You could improve upon the first method by constructing a regular expression from the regex-quoted search string framed by end markers (i.e. commas, `$` and `^`) to require a complete match, too.

The `split` way is more reliable, but it is wasteful: you end up creating a whole array of substrings, only to check for a presence of a single string, and throw away the rest.

All in all, I would prefer the first method in situations where performance matters, because it is not wasteful. If you run this method once in a while, though, the `split`-based method is easier to code and to read.

Answer (score 0):

For the case that you have mentioned contains should suffice. Split would unnecessarily end up creating an additional array which you are not using for your data processing (atleast in the above mentioned code).

Also another point that you need to consider is how many searches will you be performing in the given String. If you are performing multiple searches of String utility in the utilities String then you should think of using more complex data structures that enable multiple fast searches eg :Suffix trees.